PUT request working using postman but not using java, spring boot
I am trying to make an API call in my Spring Boot project. The PUT request is working fine using postman and I am getting 204 status code(no-content). Whereas the JAVA code is throwing 500 internal server error.
The URL generated from code (as per logs) is similar to the one in postman.
Here is the partial code:
private void subscribe() {            
    String url = "https://api.linkedin.com/rest/eventSubscriptions/(developerApplication:urn%3Ali%3AdeveloperApplication%3A{dev_app_id},user:urn%3Ali%3Aperson%3A{person_id},entity:urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A{organization_id},eventType:ORGANIZATION_SOCIAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS)";
    url.replace("{dev_app_id}", DEVELOPER_APPLICATION_ID);
    url.replace("{person_id}", "iTFpJkMpIl");
    url.replace("{organization_id}", ORGANIZATION_ID);

    // headers
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.add("X-Restli-Protocol-Version", "2.0.0");
    httpHeaders.add("LinkedIn-Version", VERSION);
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    httpHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, new StringBuilder("Bearer ").append(channel.getAccessToken()).toString());

    //body
    Webhook body = new Webhook(callback_url);
    HttpEntity<Webhook> entity = new HttpEntity<Webhook>(body, httpHeaders);
    logger.info("Hitting subscription API: {} with body: {}", url, getJson(entity.getBody()));
    logger.info("Headers: {}", entity.getHeaders().toSingleValueMap());
    try {
        restTemplate.put(url, entity);
    } catch (RestClientException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// just to check logs
private String getJson(Webhook body) {
    try {
        return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(body);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error converting object to JSON.", e);
        return "";
    }
}

The Webhook class:
public class Webhook {
    private String webhook;

    public Webhook(String webhook) {
        this.webhook = webhook;
    }

    public String getWebhook() {
        return webhook;
    }

    public void setWebhook(String webhook) {
        this.webhook = webhook;
    }
}

The documentation here states the URL required to be generated. The specific URNs are encoded.
The error:
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$InternalServerError: 500 Server Error: "{"message":"Internal Server Error","status":500}"
        at org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException.create(HttpServerErrorException.java:102)
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:186)
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:137)
        at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:942)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:891)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:790)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.put(RestTemplate.java:567)
        at com.germin8.main.services.EventSubscriber.lambda$0(EventSubscriber.java:152)
        at java.base/java.util.AbstractList$RandomAccessSpliterator.forEachRemaining(AbstractList.java:720)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
        at com.germin8.main.services.EventSubscriber.createSubscriptions(EventSubscriber.java:131)
        at com.germin8.main.services.EventSubscriber.organizarionSubscriptionMonitor(EventSubscriber.java:99)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.runInternal(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:130)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.lambda$run$2(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:124)
        at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:499)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:124)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

Here is my pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>linkedin-crawler</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>linkedin-crawler</name>
    <description>Linkedin Crawling Service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>32.1.3-jre</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>1_maven.apache.org</id>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>jcenter-snapshots</id>
          <name>jcenter</name>
          <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


I have tried

hitting the endpoint without encoding.
Using exchange instead of put.

restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.PUT, entity, String.class);

To check if the body is serialising correctly, I made a similar request to a local endpoint and it was correct too.
To check the headers, I had logged them and compared them to the ones in my postman request.

For starters stop mixing versions, remove the version tag from the spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb dependency. Second don't construct a RestTemplate because you need one, use the RestTemplateBuilder from Spring Boot to create one as a bean and expose it. Finally show what you are sending from Postman and what does your Webhook look like?

@M.Deinum thanks for pointing that out. My url from postman and code looks like https://api.linkedin.com/rest/eventSubscriptions/(developerApplication:urn%3Ali%3AdeveloperApplication%3A{dev_app_id},user:urn%3Ali%3Aperson%3A{person_id},entity:urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A{organization_id},eventType:ORGANIZATION_SOCIAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS).
The body looks like: {"webhook":"https://{ext_ip}/webhook"}.

Can you add the full code including the url and body you are using. I suspect the URL you are using is not correct and needs some additional parameters (are the place holders like {organization_id} replaced in postman?).

I have updated the code. And yes the fields dev_app_id, person_id, organization_id, access_token, ext_ip are being replaced. Also i have added the log at the end of the post (with all IDs).

Your URL is wrong. You put the encoded URL in there don't as it will be now double encoded by the rest template. Secondly you are using placeholders for which I would suggest use the RestTemplate to replace them in the URL instead of a String.replace.

I just tried using https://api.linkedin.com/rest/eventSubscriptions/(developerApplication:urn:li:developerApplication:5327785,user:urn:li:person:iTFpJkMpIl,entity:urn:li:organization:97204294,eventType:ORGANIZATION_SOCIAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS from code.
It resulted it in 400 Bad Request: "{"status":400,"code":"ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT","message":"Syntax exception in path variables"}"
Also as per documentation, I just have to encode the URNs. So the : after developerApplication in the url remains same in my opinion and the URNs will encode.

IMHO your URL is still wrong and results in double encoding. YOu aren't posting the URL as actually being used by the client as the resttemplate does processing. YOu are just posting the URL you are putting in, not what is present after processing. Those are different things. Enable debug logging to see what is actually being used instead of trying to determine that yourself. Nonetheless I still believe the problem is your URL but I removed the answer for it. For now I give up and there is probably more information in the LInkedIn documentation to helpyou.

Yes you are correct! I logged restTemplate and it is double encoding. I would really appriciate if you could suggest a solution to make a URL with the URNs encoded. Anyways thanks a lot for helping figure out the exact reason.

I would recommend that you use Spring Cloud OpenFeign for your rest requests, you will save a lot of code with that. https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-openfeign it works nicely together with autoconfiguration, you have to take care about other dependencies (like Jackson) that you will have to include to get JSON as data over the wire.

It turns out that on passing a manually encoded url, it got encoded again, which led to double encoding.
Whereas, if encoding is not performed, the PUT request doesn't encode it at all.
Don't know the exact reason of why this is the case, but here is the solution by disabling the default encoding.
DefaultUriBuilderFactory factory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory();
factory.setEncodingMode(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.NONE);
restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder()
                  .uriTemplateHandler(factory)
                  .defaultHeader("X-Restli-Protocol-Version", "2.0.0")
                  .defaultHeader("LinkedIn-Version", VERSION)
                  .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                  .build();

